# Are there any PHP web frameworks with traversal-based routing?

Tags: php, url-routing, traversal, web-frameworks

So, yesterday I've finally managed to conquer my laziness and read the Pyramid framework's documentation for a while, where I stumbled upon the [following topic](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/muchadoabouttraversal.html).

My question is: are there any PHP frameworks that support traversal as an alternative to URL dispatch..? I was unable to google anything up right away.

Comment: I'm actually just wrapping up the first open source version of a framework (Basecoat) that uses traversal for routing. https://github.com/shutterstock/basecoat